# Adding and slicing in Python's list operations

Tags: python, list, slice

I'm trying to learn list operations in Python and got stuck with some quite basic problems related to slicing and adding lists together.

PS: I apologize already in advance, but I don't understand the logic of these problems. I could not figure out even close-to solutions to these by myself. This is the last question I will ask related to slicing!

**So the first practical example:**

1. I want to create a function that takes integer as parameter and returns a list.
2. Function creates a list that equals the amount of values (starting from zero) from number 2's multiplication table.
3. Call function with different values and print the values of lists.

Example of what should be printed if given parameter is `"5"`:

```
[0,2,4,6,8]
```

**Another practical example:**

I'm given with a ready-made list:

```
l = ['I', 'have','am','yesterday','who','be','now','learned', 'how', '!','Slice', 'to'] .
```

I should call list with slice operation and combine the sliced lists in a way that when put together, they should combine the following values:

- 2 first values values of the original list
- Original list's index values 6-8 (including 8 also), which are `'now'`, `'learned'` and `'how'` values I guess
- Original list's 3 last index values in reverse order.

Thanks already in advance for the help! :)

Comment: There are too many questions here to answer. You could still update the question text with a single function showing example inputs and outputs and ask a single question about how it works (or not).

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly, strongly suggest having a go at this yourself first, as that is the way to learn, however my answers are working and are a good place to start if you're really stuck.

```
def listCreator(n):
    a = 0
    numbers = []
    for i in range(n):
        numbers.append(a)
        a += 2
    return numbers

print( listCreator(5)) # pass a number as parameter for example 5



def listDoer():
    l = ['I', 'have', 'am', 'yesterday', 'who', 'be', 'now', 'learned', 'how', '!', 'Slice', 'to']
    new_list = [l[0], l[1], l[6:9]]
    for i in range(1, 4):
        new_list.append(l[-i])
    return new_list

print( listDoer())
```

`listCreator` returns `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]` and `listDoer` returns `['I', 'have', ['now', 'learned', 'how'], 'to', 'Slice', '!']`